# Model data as list of objects or each object having an owner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating my model for a simple catologueing application I am building. It log's items, of which each item can have multiple options (itemOptions). My question is, am I best have a list of the itemOptions on the item of should the itemOptions store which item they belong to?

**Method 1**

```
public class Item
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemOption
{
    public int ItemOptionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
public class Item
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ItemOption> ItemOptions { get; set; }
}

public class ItemOption
{
    public int ItemOptionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
}
```

As the ItemOptions all belong to an item, I think Method 2 is the better way for me to model my data, although both methods work. Which is the best way to store this? Also, if I go with Method 2, how would I find out what Item them ItemOption belongs to?

Comment: I'm assuming this is for your view models? If so, it depends on what your *view needs*. Remember that your view models and your business model are *completely different things*.

Comment: This is actually for my business models, not my view models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very much depends on your domain and only you can tell which way is the best.

With **Method 2** one `ItemOption` can belong to many different `Items`, where as in **Method 1** this is Parent-Child relationship, where `ItemOption` can only belong to a single `Item`.

Comment: In this example ItemOption can only ever belong to one Item, so your answer suggests Method 1. Is there a downside to using Method 2 for this? I know technically an ItemOption could be in multiple ItemOptions lists, but if I only develop with a parent-child relationship in mind then this can be avoided?

Comment: If you want to use Method 2 for Parent-Child, you can add `int ItemId {get; set;}` to `ItemOption` and get the best from both worlds: In parent you easily get all the child, in child you always know who the parent is.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. No worries about redundant data in the database as it will be duplicated?

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework (guessing from your other question), It will insist on adding `ItemId` to `ItemOption` anyway, because DB have not simple way of simulating List of objects. So no duplication.